# Segregation of files from a downloaded torrent for seeding

Tags: windows-7, qbittorrent

I recently download a torrent of one of my favourite tv series. The problem is, they're not segregated in folders per season. I want to reseed them, but I want them in folders. Do I need to make a new `.torrent` file or can I do it using the original torrent I used to download them?

I am using QBittorrent now because Utorrent just won't install on my Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit laptop after I installed and uninstalled a software to clean and repair my laptop which i found out was a malware...

Answer (score 0):

The .torrent file keeps a log of the way it expects the downloaded files to be. So, either you conform to the way it is now, or you create a new .torrent file, with your desired folder configuration, and start seeding from scratch.

Adding more information, as there *might* be *some* exceptions to the above. It could be possible that the Torrent client could overwrite the settings embedded in the .torrent file. But that would be cumbersome, as you would need to manually change the links to conform with the folder structure you made.

It would be possible to change the .torrent file and (I am supposing at this point) use BEncode to read and alter, again manually, the .torrent files.

---

A solution could be to [hard link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) the files. Let's say you keep the files in the original place. Then, you can hard link those files to a folder structure of your liking.

The advantage is that the only thing you would need to do is to link them (as if making .lnk shortcuts) and afterwards you could use the files in your new folder structure as you wanted.

This way, you forget about the original configuration and only use the newer one, without interfering with Bittorent client settings. As hard linking is not a common practice I'll look into a way to do that easily from Windows (that I assume is your OS). For the time being there is this link to [Microsoft Technet](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil.mspx?mfr=true) and this Serverfault post ([How do you create a symbolic (hardlink) in CMD.exe](https://serverfault.com/q/75397)). Quoting the answer given:

> On an NTFS volume under Windows XP you can use the "fsutil" tool to create a hard link:
>
> `fsutil hardlink create <destination filename> <source filename>`
>
> Both source and destination must be on the same NTFS volume.

Answer (score 0):

In QBittorrent, you can try to activate smart directory settings in:

- *Options > Downloads > Saving Management > Default Torrent management*

and set to Automatic and you'll notice their save paths in details tab changed.

Basically this feature was moved from *Append labels to paths* checkbox into *Automatic/manual control* drop-down select.

So next time when you're downloading the files, select *Auto* from the top left corner and then type a label in the "Category" field.

This should segregate your files based on the label.

Source: [Move completed files to a folder according to specified torrent label](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/1908) at GitHub

Alternatively use BitTorrent which should have this out-of-box.